# CSS to embeded HTML

Tags: html, css

I am creating a profile where CSS cannot be used, as in I cannot import or direct to a CSS page, and I cannot reference css in a `<style>` tag as it doesn't work.
The only thing that seems to work is embedding CSS into HTML, since I rarely use HTML embedding new or interesting CSS has become hard, especially since HTML4 to 5, and sites aren't as clear as when HTML5 didn't exist.
For instance, this works:

```
<!-- Inliner Build Version 4380b7741bb759d6cb997545f3add21ad48f010b -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html style="font-family: sans-serif; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #000 !important; text-shadow: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 10px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<head></head>
<body style="color: #000 !important; text-shadow: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.42857143; margin: 0;" bgcolor="transparent !important">

<h1 style="font-size: 36px; color: #000 !important; text-shadow: none !important; background-color: transparent !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: inherit; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; margin: 20px 0 10px;">lel</h1>
<h2>Work in progress</h2>

<ol type="1">
  <li>TopDave/li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>  

</body>
</html>
```

but I used an gmail HTML to email generator and it missed the majority of the CSS, is there an easy way to convert the CSS, or like a chart to show how I can embed it?

Comment: But you can probably use `<style>...</style>` I guess.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, it hid the script tag I put in, it just wont workj, it prints the css like normal text

Comment: No, I doubt there is an application / framework / library to do this as inline-css is very much discouraged. You will have to go through and convert the styles to inline-css individually

Comment: is there a referrence? because sometimes I just dont know how to turn the CSS into embedded html

Comment: It's called inline css. You just take everything inside the rule ( curly brackets ) and make it all one line. CSS is the same whether it is within a CSS rule or in inline CSS.

Comment: okay so if ive got a nice css list, how would I embed it into the htmlo lsit above, I am truely not sure

Comment: [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/humbleRumble/d4fd47ffc3fadfc4f240) @ping me if you still don't understand.